# Bootsrap jQuery carousel images stack one over another

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a problem with my carousel, in the same form it was working on other webpage I was working on, however now it kinda works but it shows like below:
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6U8e.jpg)

Three images are stack one on top of another instead of showing just one and change them from time to time.

Here is my HTML and CSS for that particular page:

```css
/********
GENERAL
********/

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #2aabd2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/********
BODY
********/

body {
    background: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

/********
HEADER
********/

header {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #000000;
    height: 60px;
}

h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 32px;
}

/********
NAVBAR
********/

header h1 {
    flex-grow: 2;
}

header ul {
    flex-grow: 5;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

/********
SECTION
********/

section {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

/********
FOOTER
********/

footer {
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    background: #000000;
}

/********
CAROUSEL
********/

.carousel {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel .item {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 90vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
    <section class="container">

        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/wordpress18.jpg" alt="Slide1">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/wordpress7.jpg" alt="Slide2">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/wordpress1.jpg" alt="Slide3">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div> <!-- Carousel -->

    </section>
```

Any clues? I just can't find any mistakes for last few hours

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, did you include the bootstrap and jquery <script> tags in your HTML (easy thing to overlook)

Comment: Yes I did, in the bottom of the HTML - below footer - I just didn't include whole HTML in the snippet.

Comment: @MaciekJarmula it should work https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/kd80zphr/1/ but you must place the bootstrap css file INSIDE THE HEAD tag and not at the bottom of HTML.